# The crt file in the stripe extension keeps changing

Tags: stripe

I run 4 different instances of CiviCRM on very similar Digital Oceans Ubuntu droplets but on one of them I periodically get the error in the system status:

> Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 77]: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /var/www/live/web/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/data/ca-certificates.crt CApath: /etc/ssl/certs)

When I look at the ca-certificates.crt file, it is no longer a certificate file and has changed to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at curl.haxx.se Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

If I replace this file with the original file, the error goes away but it always happens again, maybe a week later, maybe 3 months later.

Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?